# How to solve a linearised system around a critical point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

Considering a nonlinear autonomous system:

$\frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F(x,y) \\ G(x,y) \end{bmatrix}$

Suppose $(x,y)=(a,b)$ is a critical point of the system and we want to linearise around this point:

Setting $z_1 = x - a, z_2 = y-b$ we obtain:

$\frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F_x(a,b) & F_y(a,b) \\ G_x(a,b) & G_y(a,b) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}$

This is where I have confusion, can I simply solve the linearised system for $z_1, z_2$ then if I want a solution for $x(t),y(t)$ I can simply just add $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} $ on the rhs of the solution for $ \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}$?

Furthermore, the critical point of a system is a particular solution of the linearised system around that point? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why do you want to solve the linearized system? Normally we only linearize the system in order to determine the stability of the equilibrium points/critical points.

Comment: Indeed you might only be interested in the eigenvalues of the linearised system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the linearized system at the equilibrium points you need to solve:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix} x-a \\ y-b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F_x(a,b) & F_y(a,b) \\ G_x(a,b) & G_y(a,b) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x-a \\ y-b \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\implies \frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F_x(a,b) & F_y(a,b) \\ G_x(a,b) & G_y(a,b) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} F_x(a,b) & F_y(a,b) \\ G_x(a,b) & G_y(a,b) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$$

This is an inhomogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients. The solution vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ is given as the linear superposition of the homogeneous solution $\boldsymbol{x}_{\text{h}}$ of the system

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_h = \begin{bmatrix} F_x(a,b) & F_y(a,b) \\ G_x(a,b) & G_y(a,b) \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_h$$

and the particular solution $\boldsymbol{x}_{\text{p}}=\begin{bmatrix}a,b\end{bmatrix}^T$ (verify by plugging into the differential equation).

Hence, the solution is given as

$$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=\boldsymbol{x}_{\text{h}}(t)+[a,b]^T.$$

As $\boldsymbol{x}_{\text{h}}$ is nothing but the solution for your system in $z_i$ you were right in assuming that you could simply add $[a,b]^T$ to the solution to obtain the solution for $\boldsymbol{x}(t)$.

Comment: Isn't the linearization just an approximation to the system? If $(a,b)$ was just $(0,0)$, we would still get not precisely a solution, but something close. Recall the small oscillations for a pendulum, $x''= -\sin x$, gets approximated by $x'' = -x$, very well indeed.

Comment: This works if the Taylor series of the function does have linear terms, for example, $x''=-x^2$ and $z''=+z^2$ both give the same linearized equations (at the origin) $\hat{x}''=0$ or $\hat{z}''=0$. But that is a very good point.